# problem with show legend in pivot mode and serverside render

Tags: ag-grid

I have problem in legend chart , when my report is pivot and rowGroup i want show legend with per group title and measure like this when grid in **client side mode**

[[image: client side pivot[1]]

but when grid is

```
rowModelType: 'serverSide'
```

mode legend show this way

[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqyaRjxQjQPnuVPGrHHK?p=preview)

[image]

Please guide me.